# CountdownTimer: How to restart from a remaining time when the user goes back to the previous activity?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm beginner in Android and it might be really basic question.
I'm trying to create a `CountDownTimer` which keeps countdown between two activities. Users can go to the Activity B and go back to Activity A from Activity B.
And I am thinking of saving the remaining time in `SharedPreferences`. What I want to know is when the user does `OnBackPressed` and save the current remaining time into `SharedPreferences` and goes back to the previous activity, how can I restart the countdown timer from the remaining time in previous activity?

Comment: To get clear understanding of your question I want to know. If user press back button at this time 5 seconds are left and user switches the screen and stays there for 3 seconds and now while swtiching the screen you had 5 seconds. What you want is to show from 5 seconds or from 2 seconds as the user has already spent 3 seconds on other activity?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed from 2 seconds. Basically what I am trying to create is CountdownTimer which keeps between activities. Sorry if I still don't get your comment.

Comment: You got my comment right. But your question was little confusing that's y I asked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this method should help you:

```
@Override
public void onResume() { // This will be trigger when your activity is created or come to front
    // Load preference
    // Start timer
}

@Override
public void onStop() { // This will be triggered when your activity goes behind or before your activity destroyed.
   // Cancel timer
   // Save preference
}
```

It's really simple, just follow the comments. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks your comment is easy to understand. I will try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

To get this, you must have a separate thread to calculate count down stuff and it will be running all way weather you are at on Activity 1 or another activity. And that thread should update the activity(Check if activity is visible). To update the activity there can be various way.

1. You can use thread and update the activity via broadcast
2. You can use thread and check for the activity visibility, if that is visible do the stuff accordingly.
3. As you are already using **shared preference**, you can achieve the same thing via shared preference as well. You can use thread/service and update the **shared preference** on every tick or every second. And when you get **onResume** call back of the activity. get the value back from **shared preference** and use it accordingly.

Hope this will help you.